# matlab: 2D line plot horizontal lines

Tags: matlab, plot, 2d, histogram

This is actually very basic and I've done it before (a long tme ago) but I can't find it now; I have a vector of data points that I want to plot with a line plot; however I want the lines to be horizontal and jump between each point so that it basically looks like a histogram. I thought I could just use *plot()* with a certain linespec, but I can't find one that fits. Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is `stairs`:

```
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi,40);
stairs(x,sin(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let `x` and `y` be two vectors of the same size to be plotted using `plot(x,y)`. How about

```
yy = reshape( [y(:) y(:)]', 1, [] );
yy(end) = []; % discard last element
xx = reshape( [x(:) x(:)]', 1, [] );
xx(1) = []; % discard first element
plot( xx, yy );
title('does this do the trick for you?');
```